# Anova test p-values - R

Tags: r, loops, testing, statistics, anova

I am pretty new to R. I need to perform anova tests for a set of around 40 proteins against 2 clinical variables (both categorical). I need to obtain all p-values for each single protein, but when I use aov() and summary() to visualise the results obtained from the test, only one p-value appears.
How can I view all the p-values for each of the proteins?
Thank you!

I attached here a screenshot of my code [anova tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUapW.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()` and use the [reprex-package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I added a screenshot of my code, thank you!

Comment: With "anova ig" I refer to the test for the iss_group; then I will do another one separately for inf

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Copy&paste [the code itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079492/anova-test-p-values-r?noredirect=1#comment122090310_69079492), not a screenshot of it.